# Word count script in Python

Tags: python, urllib, urlopen

Can someone please explain me why there is 'b' in front of each word and how to get read of it? Script returns something like this:

> word= b'yesterday,' , count = 3

```
current_word = {}
current_count = 0
text = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KseniaGiansar/pythonProject2_text/master/yesterday.txt"
request = urllib.request.urlopen(text)
each_word = []
words = None
count = 1
same_words ={}
word = []

# сollect words into a list
for line in request:
    #print "Line = " , line
    line_words = line.split()
    for word in line_words:  # looping each line and extracting words
        each_word.append(word)
for words in each_word:
    if words.lower() not in same_words.keys() :
        same_words[words.lower()]=1
    else:
        same_words[words.lower()]=same_words[words.lower()]+1
for each in same_words.keys():
    print("word = ", each, ", count = ",same_words[each])
```

Comment: `each.decode()`, in order to get a string instead of bytes.

Comment: Also, look at the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indicating that the variable `words` is a bytes object.

`urllib.request.urlopen()` returns a bytes object.

To fix this, you can use the `.decode()` method to convert the bytes object to a string before appending it to the list.

```
for line in request:
    line_words = line.decode().split() # decode the bytes object to a string
    for word in line_words:
        each_word.append(word)
```

Answer (score 1):

B-strings in python are byte strings.

When you are reading from an HTTP request, the response is in bytes, and you should decode it like this:

```py
line_words = line.decode("utf8").split()
```

Please make sure the encoding of your string (UTF-8 in my example) matches the charset in the `Content-Type` header of the request. You can send an `Accept-Charset: utf-8` header in the request to tell the server to return a UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 1):

the b prolly means bytes

i think you can remove the "b" decoding the bytes into a string using the .decode() method. In this case, you can add the following line before the for loop:

```
line = line.decode("utf-8")
```

You can also remove the ️ from each word, before adding it to the each_word list by doing the following:

```
word = word.decode("utf-8")
```